# Combine polygons in a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, merge

[image]

I am trying to build a model in arcmap that (1) converts a raster to polygon (2) dissolves the polygons by landcover class (3) adds a field that calculates area of the landcover polygons. I want to combine all the polygons of different landcover classes into a single record for each class so I have the total area for the class instead of multiple polygons for each class with their own area.

I know how to manually merge records in Editor, but how do I build it into my model?

Comment: Try dissolve on this field with multipart option on.

Comment: I have, it still makes multiple polygons of the same class

Comment: It seems you hit a wall. This might happen when certain number of vertices per polygon exceeded.